# Starting VNC server on startup on RaspberryPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, vnc, raspberry-pi4, vnc-server

I would like the VNC server of my RPi 4 to start automatically on startup (for both local and internet connection). I followed the guidelines of the [RealVNC website](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002249917-VNC-Connect-and-Raspberry-Pi#operating-vnc-server-at-the-command-line-0-6). Hence I used the command :

```
sudo systemctl enable vncserver-x11-serviced.service
```

But it doesn't work (for both connection type), I got a timeout. Then I tried [this solution](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-lesson-7-remote-control-with-vnc/running-vncserver-at-startup) with a autostart file like that:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=TightVNC
Exec=vncserver :1
StartupNotify=false
```

But same, the VNC server doesn't start automatically after a reboot. The SSH connection works fine, so, at least the local VNC should work. Even when I use the command to start the VNC server, I cannot connect.

What can be the issue? I don't know if you need more informations? I'm trying to connect to the VNC server via the Viewer on Windows. It was working when I launched the server the first time with the GUI (now I'm using the Pi without screen).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since few years now, there is an integrated tool to enable/disable many stuff including vnc and ssh.

Maybe just remove the changes you've done manually before.

Then run: `sudo raspi-config`

This is a "graphical" (curses style, in console) app to changes many basic raspberry options.
You should be able to enable VNC server at boot in menu "Interfacing Options".

*More information on this tool here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md*

Comment: Thanks, I enabled the VNC and now it's running on startup :)